# how to send email attachement from iphone application using local file

Tags: iphone, email, pdf-generation

I want to send the local file from resources folder to email but it is not working is there how to add the local file.Below is the code which sends email from documents folders of iphone but i want from resource folder

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString*giveFileName=@"CPAC_Contract_Equine"; 
NSString *fileName;
//fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",giveFileName];

fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",giveFileName];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSLog(pdfFileName);

NSMutableData *myPdfData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
[picker setSubject:@"CPAC Contract for Equine-Sam Veterinarian"];

[picker addAttachmentData:myPdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:giveFileName];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: First of, what resource folder? You mean the the Resources group in the Xcode project, those file are just added to the app bundle.

Comment: @rckoenes yes you are rigt resource group in xcode as we normally add any image in xcode like this

Answer (score 0):

The code you post is almost correct, you just need to the file path the path of the file in app bundle. Replace this part of the code:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

Just make it load the file from the bundle:

```
 NSString *pdfFileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

Comment: what will ne mime type of the file can you please write or edit in my code so it works it is not working

Comment: i have tried this show in message dialog but it does not get attached after sending email

Comment: I have no idea what the mime type is, since I do not know the file you are trying to attach to the email. Also in the code I post you will find how to get file paths for files in the app bundle. This should get you going to write your own solution.

Comment: /Users/malikwahajahmed/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F6F1163B-7A66-4EA3-89A7-218C6C327C5F/CPAC.app/W9.pdf
 it shows this path this is not the app bundle path i think it is documents directory path

Comment: Nope that is the App budle path. Did you make sure that the PDF is include in the project, check if the file is in the `Copy Bundle Resources` list of the project

Comment: Then you will have to check that the file is really in the bundle. Just open the bundle and verify that the file is there.